# want to show the dragging over container div which is having scrolling

Tags: html, css, jquery

I want to drag my `<div>` from one container to another container. But in that case whenever I drag my `div` then the scrolling is done & the dragged `div` is dragged inside of the container itself.

My HTML code is as below:

```
<fieldset class="span4">
    <legend>Builder</legend>
    <div class="builder scrollspy-example" id="builderBox" data-spy="scroll" style="height: 600px;" data-bind="foreach:items">
        <div class='media draggable alert alert-block fade in' data-bind="attr:{'data-id':ID}">
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button>
            <div class='row'>
                <legend><h4 class='media-heading' data-bind="text:Title" style='margin-left: 30px;'></h4></legend>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-left: 5px;">
                <div class='pull-left'>
                    <img class='media-object' data-bind="attr:{src:'http://images.vidzapper.com/'+ImageUrl+'?w=60&h=60'}" style='width: 60px; height: 60px;' />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="span4">
    <legend>Organizer</legend>
    <div class="Organizer  scrollspy-example" id="drop" data-spy="scroll" style="height: 600px;">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

and my Script code is as below::

```
$("#drop").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        console.log("drop");
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({ top: 0, left: 0 }).appendTo(droppedOn);
    }
});
$("#drop").sortable();
```

what I should use so that the dragging is shown over the container?

Comment: I ran your code via jsFiddle but found out that it's not currently working. Do you mean to have your dragged div to `snap` onto the parent div whenever dragged into its radius?

Comment: yes I am able to drag & drop but while dragging it doesn't show dragging over the div. It shows dragging done inside of that div only in which it is currently

Comment: Can you check this [link](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to) and get back to me if this somehow, satisfies your requirement? Moreover, here is the jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/KevinIsNowOnline/LWufL/) that I'm talking about.

Comment: I Found the Answer & Thanx for your comments @KevinIsNowOnline.

I just have to make a Container div & at the time of draggable() I have to write it as,
-----------------------------------------------------------
$(".draggable").draggable({ cursor: "crosshair", opacity: 0.7, revert: "invalid", helper: 'clone', appendTo: 'div #container' });